# Adding EditText to Alert Dialog.

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code that create alert dialog and I added two edit text to it but once I run the app the values within the EditText won't be retrived and my app crash with NullPointerException:

the code is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
        final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
        final EditText passwordInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);   
        alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null));
        alert.setTitle("Enter Password");
        alert.setMessage("Enter password to remove the app:");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //provide user with caution before uninstalling
            //also here should be added a AsyncTask that going to read the password and once its checked the password is correct the app will be removed
            value1=usernameInput.getText().toString();
            value2=passwordInput.getText().toString();
            if(value1.equals(null)&&value2.equals(null))
            {Toast.makeText(context, "Enter username and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
         }
        });
        });
        alert.show();
```

Comment: You call wrong findViewById. Call alert.findViewByID

Comment: thanks Yahor10, but I tried to do it your way and keep getting an error since there is no function called alert.findViewById(); the only thing that I got is this.findViewById() which also did not work.. but Any how I posted the solution that I used to solve this problem below..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks guys for your contributions in answering my question, and I think I got the solution for the problem that I posted above which is:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyFeedActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=MyFeedActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);       
        alert.setView(layout);
        final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
        final EditText passwordInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
```

and I think the problem was that I cannot get the EidtText within the alert dialog, but by doing it by the above code every thing works just fine with me.

Answer (score 14):

use this:

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setHint("hint");
    alertDialog.setTitle("title");
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setView(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing like this

```
final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
final EditText passwordInput=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
```

OR

```
final EditText usernameInput=(EditText)alert.findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
final EditText passwordInput=(EditText)alert.findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
```